# Cannot read property 'gmail' of undefined - Javascript only

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I am using Google's GMail API to get the number of unread emails (and list them) in my email account.

I have the code straight out of Google's sample (below). Console returns: "Cannot read property 'gmail' of undefined". I have found nothing that states that gmail must be defined. What am I missing?

```
var query = "is:unread";
var userId = "me";

function listMessages(userId, query, callback) {
  var getPageOfMessages = function(request, result) {
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      result = result.concat(resp.messages);
      var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
      if (nextPageToken) {
        request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
          'userId': userId,
          'pageToken': nextPageToken,
          'q': query
        });
        getPageOfMessages(request, result);
      } else {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  };
  var initialRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
    'userId': userId,
    'q': query
  });
  getPageOfMessages(initialRequest, []);
}
```

Comment: _“I have found nothing that states that `gmail` must be defined.”_ — what does that have to do with the error you’re getting? `gapi.client` is `undefined`, not `gmail`.

Comment: To clarify what Xufox means in a friendlier way, there needs to be a definition for the gapi object you're invoking. Likely their sample covered that somewhere else and it wasn't included in the code snippet above.

Comment: Following the [Browser Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js), you'll need to the script with `scr="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"` to enable your website to use Google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the script `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` somewhere in your HTML document.

That is the Google Javacsript Client library that defines the `gapi` variable.  If you try to use `gapi` before it's defined, you get the error you're seeing.

See:  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

At the very top of the HTML file:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```